# how to obtain values as that of matplotlib's date2num

Tags: python, date, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

I want to find the y intercept of a linear line. For that, i tried to use numpy's polyfit(), and it doesnt take arguments as datetime, therefore i converted datetime to matplotlib's date2num and next time i tried converting the same dates using `time.mktime(datetime.timetuple())` to obtain the same result of what matplotlib's date2num produced:

```
x1 = 2015-07-20 00:00:00
x2 = 2015-07-31 00:00:00
idx = [x1, x2]
y1 = 132.97
y2 = 122.642

# to vary the position of y-intercept i used foo
bar =  2015-07-31 00:00:00
foo = matplotlib.dates.date2num(bar) # returns = 735810.0

x = matplotlib.dates.date2num(idx)
y = [y1, y2]

x[0]
>>> 735799.0
x[1]
>>> 735810.0

coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
x_axis = np.linspace(x[0], foo + 1, 3)  # linspace(start, end, num)
y_axis = polynomial(x_axis)
>>>[ 132.97        127.33654545  121.70309091] # y_axis output
y-intecept = y_axis[2]
print("y-intercept = ', y-intercept)
>>>121.703090909
```

And when i try to convert `x1, x2` using `time.mktime(datetime.timetuple())` instead of `matplotlib.dates.date2num(idx)` like below, i get different result.

```
dx1 = time.mktime(x1.timetuple())
dx2 = time.mktime(x2.timetuple())
x = [dx1, dx2]
...
...
...
print("y-intercept = ', y-intercept)
>>> 122.641989133
```

How can i obtain the result like matplotlib's date2num, without using `matplotlib` library so that i can get the result `121.703090909` produced during usage of `date2num`.

Comment: `x1 = 2015-07-20 00:00:00+00:00` is invalid syntax. How exactly do you define `x1`?

Comment: actually that date was returned from datetime(), i pasted that output here to simplify things.

Comment: Do not simplify things this way. One needs a [mcve] to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Now it shall work, can you check now?

Comment: `x1 = 2015-07-20 00:00:00` is still invalid syntax. It's you who needs to check if your code is working, not me.

Answer (score 0):

You may reproduce the result of `matplotlib.dates.date2num` by essentially copying the code from the [matplotlib.dates source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/dates.py):

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

class _UTC(datetime.tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(0)
    def tzname(self, dt):
        return str("UTC")
    def dst(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(0)
UTC = _UTC()

def date2num(dt):
    tzi = getattr(dt, 'tzinfo', None)
    if tzi is not None:
        dt = dt.astimezone(UTC)
        tzi = UTC
    base = float(dt.toordinal())
    cdate = getattr(dt, 'date', lambda: None)()
    if cdate is not None:
        midnight_time = datetime.time(0, tzinfo=tzi)
        rdt = datetime.datetime.combine(cdate, midnight_time)
        base += (dt - rdt).total_seconds() / (60*60*24.)
    return base

x1 = datetime.datetime(2015,07,20)   # Datetime object without hours, minutes, seconds
x2 = datetime.datetime(2015,07,31,4,50) # Datetime object with hours, minutes

print x1.toordinal() # 735799 
print x2.toordinal() # 735810  hours, minutes, seconds get truncated

print date2num(x1) # 735799.0
print date2num(x2) # 735810.201389

import matplotlib.dates
print matplotlib.dates.date2num(x1) # 735799.0
print matplotlib.dates.date2num(x2) # 735810.201389
```

Note that if you only use dates without time, the conversion is as simple as

`x1.toordinal()`